# All my xml files have errors in AndroidStudio Project

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle

looks like all xml files AndroidManifest.xml and res xml files have errors, like "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)" and "Attribute android: is not allowed here" errors.

For example this is my manifest file:

```
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

<permission
        android:name="spartons.com.javadriverapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/map_api_key"/>

</application>
```

xmlns:android and xmlns:tool tags have URI errors and most of android tags have attribute is not allowed.

This is my app build.graddle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "spartons.com.javadriverapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the mirror project files of symbolic link have all the errors whereas the originals don't

[image]

The originals files are under /mnt whereas ~/ holds its symbolic mirror. The pictures shows AndroidManifest.xml with errors and one of them has "uri not registerd" error

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the schema of tools and android attributes in the top or parent layout of the xml

like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and if its already there still getting error then click ALT + ENTER  on the first line of the layout

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but apparently the problem occurs on the mirror project files of symbolic link. For some reason those files have the errors whereas the originals don't.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot for the errored file? if possible.

Comment: I put the screenshot on the answer

Comment: Try this go to File->invalidate/restart

Comment: I tried that before I had realized the problem cause. This problem is closed.